# Sikuli is not recognize the image but earlier it was recognizing it

Tags: sikuli

I am using the sikuli with java and eclipse IDE. I have captured some images and created a repository of images. My code was working fine with captured images and I was able to login into my Desktop Application and able open a project. But now after few days, sikuli is not recognizing those captured images Please help me out

https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/289295

Comment: happens when the background is changed

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Here I list some possible reasons:

1. Have you changed the screen resolution?
2. As SnakeFoot mention, if you're using click over the desktop and you have changed your background image, the images could been changed.

PD: Sorry, my english is not perfect.